# Dismissal Error

Tags: ios, swift

I have a setup that brings up a date picker upon clicking of a button. I have two a function that changes the value of a button upon selecting a date. In addition, I also have a function that should help dismiss the date picker when I press the done button. However, I continue to get an error stating 'unrecognized selector sent to instance'. Any idea what I could have possibly done wrong

```
 @IBOutlet weak var dueDateSelector: UIButton!
 @IBOutlet weak var myPickerView: UIPickerView!

@IBAction func changeDueDate(_ sender: Any) {
    //Create the view
    let inputView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x:0, y:420, width: self.view.frame.width, height: 240))
    var datePickerView  : UIDatePicker = UIDatePicker(frame: CGRect(x:0, y:40, width:0, height:0))
    datePickerView.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerMode.date
    inputView.addSubview(datePickerView) // add date picker to UIView
    let doneButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x:270, y:0, width:100, height:50))
    doneButton.setTitle("Done", for: UIControlState.normal)
    doneButton.setTitle("Done", for: UIControlState.highlighted)
    doneButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.black, for: UIControlState.normal)
    doneButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.gray, for: UIControlState.highlighted)
    inputView.addSubview(doneButton) // add Button to UIView
    doneButton.addTarget(self, action: "doneButton:", for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside) // set button click event
    datePickerView.addTarget(self, action: Selector("handleDatePicker:"), for: UIControlEvents.valueChanged)
    view.addSubview(inputView)
    handleDatePicker(sender: datePickerView) // Set the date on start.

}

  @objc func handleDatePicker(sender: UIDatePicker) {
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
    dueDateSelector.setTitle(dateFormatter.string(from: sender.date), for: .normal)
}

@objc func doneButton(sender:UIButton)
{
    dueDateSelector.resignFirstResponder() // To resign the inputView on clicking done.
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to an inconsistency in naming methods between Swift and Objective C. This is also why you should write selectors with the `#selector` syntax instead of using strings. You need to change this line:

```
datePickerView.addTarget(self, action: Selector("handleDatePicker:"), for: UIControlEvents.valueChanged)
```

Selectors are an Objective C thing. If you write it in strings, then you need to write it in an Objective C fashion. In your code, `handleDatePicker` is not actually called `handleDatePicker:` in Objective C. It is probably something like `handleDatePickerWithSender:`. This is because you have a `sender` argument there, and that becomes the `WithSender` part in the eyes of Objective C.

This is why we like to write selectors like this:

```
#selector(handleDatePicker)
```

No need to worry about parameters, just the method name.

```
datePickerView.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleDatePicker), for: UIControlEvents.valueChanged)
```

Also, this line needs to be changed as well:

```
doneButton.addTarget(self, action: "doneButton:", for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
```

It should be:

```
doneButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(doneButton), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
```

Comment: can I maybe ask one more thing

Comment: @RonBaker I think that is out of the scope of this question, Here are a few things that I recommend you to include in your new question, show how you are presenting the picker view in the first place. Is it just a view in the same VC? Is it presented modally as a popup? You should also show how you want to dismiss the date picker view. Do you just want it to become invisible?

Comment: ahh okay welp new question it is

Answer (score 0):

I think you are having problem here,

```
@objc func doneButton(sender:UIButton)
{
    dueDateSelector.resignFirstResponder() // To resign the inputView on clicking done.
}
```

here dueDateSelector is button which is not having any method called resignFirstResponder() so that's why you are getting error

instead you can do this,

```
@objc func doneButton(sender:UIButton)
    {
        //remove or hide the input view
    }
```

You can also check that whether current component having this method or not with,

```
if dueDateSelector.canResignFirstResponder()
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using deprecated string selector syntax:

```
doneButton.addTarget(self, action: "doneButton:", for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
```

Should be replaced with:

```
doneButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(doneButton(sender:)),
                             for: .touchUpInside)
```

It's also applied to the other method in your code:

```
datePickerView.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleDatePicker(sender:)),
                         for: .valueChanged)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
doneButton.addTarget(self, action:#selector(self.doneButton(_:)) , for:
    UIControlEvents.touchUpInside) // set button click event
datePickerView.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.handleDatePicker(_:)), for: UIControlEvents.valueChanged)
```

if self wont work use class reference like yourClass().doneButton